# APx hardness of Multiterminal Cut Problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, approximation-hardness

In a Multiterminal Cut problem input is a graph G=(V,E) and a set of k terminals T which is a subset of vertex set V. There is a weight w(e) associated with each edge in the graph. The question is to find the minimum weight edge set whose removal will disconnect every terminal to every other terminal in T. The following things are known about the problem:

1. k = O(1), Degree of any vertex unbounded, edge weights = O(1)
   APX hard
2. k = O(1), Degree of any vertex = O(1), edge weights unbounded
   APX hard
3. k unbounded, Degree of any vertex = O(1), edge weights = O(1)
   NP hard
4. k = O(1), Degree of any vertex = O(1), edge weights equal
   Poly time.

Is there a result which says that the problem with " k unbounded, Degree of any vertex = O(1), edge weights = O(1)" is also APX-hard? Any ideas on proving this will be useful.